# How to restrict CouchDB to serverside updates

Tags: security, nginx, couchdb, pouchdb, updating

I'm quite new to couchdb. We took couchdb/pouchdb for an react webapp. Its a quite simple app where a user can search in a list, pick 10 favourites and submit these as his voting. A top 10 List of the items with the most votes ist also implemented.
Everything works but I'd be happy to get some feedback to the used security concept.

At first load the item list database is replicated from server to client (couch to pouch) through a view:

```js
 db.replicate.from(COUCH_URL + DB_NAME, {
    live: true,
    filter: '_view',
    view: 'items/allItems'
});
```

The items have a property "votes". Incrementing user votes must be done serverside, on the one hand to avoid conflicts on the other hand to restrict to set value other than +1. We didn't want wo use serverside code outside couchdb.

In a _design document we implemented an update function to do this:

```js
{
    "_id": "_design/item",
    "_rev": "...",
    "views": {
        "allItems": {
            "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.interpreter) emit(doc._id); }"
        }
    },
    "updates": {
        "voteForItem": "function(doc, req) {
                 if (!doc) {
                      return [null, {
                          'code': 400,
                          'json': {
                              'error': 'missed',
                              'reason': 'no document to update'
                          }
                      }]
                  } else {
                      if (!doc.votes) {
                          doc.votes = 0;
                      }
                      doc.votes += 1;
                      return [doc, {
                          'json': {
                              'status': 'ok'
                          }
                      }];
                  }
              }"
    }
}
```

The continuous replication then fetches the changes vote values, triggers an local change and react sets updates the view.

**These are the database permissions and security an what we did to fulfill our needs:**

In couchdb there is not much to do:

- couch security:

  - set db admin user to restrict write access to design docs
  - not set db member user to be able to write vote changes. with a user the credentials had to be in client js so this is not better
- validate_doc_update:

  - nothing here since

    - to restrict changes on vote property is not helpful
    - can't check if request comes direct to docs REST url or by an update function (could be helpful in future couch versions)
    - it's not possible to change the doc here (just to increment votes)

So we decided to use nginx as reverse proxy to define access restrictions:

```js
location /db {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    if ($request_method ~* GET) {
        rewrite /db/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
    }
    if ($request_method !~* GET) {
        return 403;
    }
}


location ~ ^/db/(.*)/(_local|_bulk_get|_update) {
        rewrite /db/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location ~ ^/db/(.*)/_changes {
    rewrite /db/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

- mapping couchdb on /db
- permit only GET to allow replication
- allow other than GET on _updates to call serverside update function
- allow other than GET on _local and _bulk_get to make continuous replication work again
- same on _changes but with proxy_buffering off

Of course direct access to couchdb is limited to 127.0.0.1.

**Is the database with these settings secure or did I miss anything?**

Which concept or architecture would you have used?

To restrict users to vote multiple times only a flag in a local pouch + a cookie are set since the users may not be forced to register. This of course is "unsecure" but lets ignore this.